# Starting Activity from the Preference Screen in XML?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-preferences

The Activity I want to start is defined in my *androidmanifest.xml* like so:

```
<activity
    android:name="about"
    android:label=""
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.nick.simplequiz.paid.ABOUT" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And this is how I attempt to call it from my preference screen:

```
<Preference android:title="About"
    android:key="about">
    <intent android:action="com.nick.simplequiz.paid.ABOUT"/>
</Preference>
```

When the app runs and I click on the preference, it doesn't actually appear to open the Activity. It just closes the settings preference Activity. What is the correct way to accomplish this?

Comment: @ManveerChawla I did search the community, and previously had seen that question, but was unable to solve my issue with that question

Answer (score 0):

Your problem that the activity name is case-sensitive so you need to use the same naming in the class name, manifest and preferences xml

Also the activity name should be preceeded by a "." or to give it a path yourpackage.path.to.activity

Comment: OK I understand that, but what I don't understand is where the name must be changed. Changing the name inside the preference causes a crash because it says "No activity found to handle intent". Is the android:action="" line supposed to say something different?

Comment: In the manifest , the intent filter at the end there is ABOUT change it to about and change the activity name to .ABOUT... see my edit

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--Manifest Example-->
        <activity
            android:name="com.nick.simplequiz.paid.ABOUT"
            android:label=""
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.nick.simplequiz.paid.ABOUT" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    <!--XML example-->
    <Preference android:title="About"
        android:key="about">

        <intent android:action="com.nick.simplequiz.paid.ABOUT"/>

    </Preference>
```